# Sync an html file on my computer as a public webpage

Tags: html, file, synchronization

I have an HTML file which is being automatically generated by a python script. Is it possible to create a setup such that this file becomes a webpage, from the point of view of a random user? Basically I want to be able to send a link to my friends to view the webpage, and have it set up so that when I re-run the python script, the webpage will be updated (after a browser refresh). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're looking for a way to publish a website, I've got an easy way. But, it's not as simple as re-running your code, you need to deploy your work. Now here's what I'd do.

1. Go to [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)
2. Make an account and a team (if necessary)
3. Create a project and put your code folder in there.
4. When you've edited your code, go to the deploy section, and insert the updated folder.
5. To change the URL, go to settings and press domain. You can then create a domain of your choice (with the .netlify.com extension)
6. Or you can buy one at places like [Hostinger](https://hostinger.com) or [Freenom](https://freenom.com)